# BuddyPress: What's the use of wp_bp_xprofile_data table and how does it get updated?

Tags: database, buddypress, table

I have a questions related to BuddyPress:
 What's the use of `wp_bp_xprofile_data` table? How does the data in the table get updated?
And when any user updates his information - does the data in this table get updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wp_bp_xprofile_data` table holds all of the custom fields used on the front-end by BuddyPress. It is independent of the WordPress user meta.

All of the functions that interact with this table can be found in [`bp-xprofile/bp-xprofile-functions.php`](https://buddypress.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/bp-xprofile/bp-xprofile-functions.php).